# GMail IRC-like notify

Tags: gmail

Is there some gmail / firefox / greasemonkey plugin, that enables in gmail a notify option, kinda like in IRC ?

To for example, bleeeps, when someone comes online.

I'll gladly consider all other options as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a combo of [Growl](http://growl.info/) on a Mac with Firefox with the [Yip](http://abcdefu.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/introducing-yip-an-unified-notification-system-for-the-web/) extension plus [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) plus a  [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/46637) to fire the notification when new emails come in.

Seems that there is another [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/53183) that works with [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/) - you could try that?

Comment: or use pidgin and it's plugins, but if you have to use the web interface, his idea works best

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw - Sounds like a plan. Off to try it!